# Saving Mat from OpenCV to Smartphone's memory

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am currently having difficulties in saving bitmaps in Android. I am working on a system that detects the eye region of a person. I have this code which saves the ROI to a Mat in opencv.

```
Rect eyearea_right = new Rect( RectOfFace.x + RectOfFace.width / 16 ,
                    (int) (RectOfFace.y + (RectOfFace.height / 4.5)) ,
                    (RectOfFace.width - 2 * RectOfFace.width / 16) / 2,
                    (int) (RectOfFace.height / 3.0)
            );

ROI = new Mat(mGray, eyearea_left);
                Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) ROI.size().width, (int) ROI.size().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

However, I am having difficulties in saving it to the phone's storage. I need to see the image or the bitmap in order for me to know how I will process the image to detect if the person is closing his/her eyes. Also, is there a way to print/display the bitmap derived from the Mat in OpenCV on the screen? Thank you.

This is the code for saving that I have found in the internet

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
                Log.i("Bitmap", root);
                myDir.mkdirs();
                int n = i;
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, "/saved_images/" + "image" + i + ".jpg");
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver()
                        , file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
```

Comment: What is your difficulty in saving.

Comment: I copied a code block from the internet. It saves the bitmap as a jpg file. However, it only saves a black image. I have edited the description above and added the code for saving the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a bitmap yes. But it has nothing to do with ROI. Only dimensions are taken. Not content. So it is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, greenapps. May I ask how do I get the image bounded by the rectangle? Thanks.

Comment: No idea. Don't know Mat.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought you may have an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my problem. Basically, you need to use the submat function in order for you to get a part of the Mat. The submat is a function that is available in the Mat class.